# как парсить json массив

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

Добрый день!
Имеется json файл ( http://androiddocs.ru/api/friends.json с такими данными

```
{"data":"dbfriends",
"friends": [{"id":"1","name":"Andrew","city":"Moscow","contacts":{"mobile":"+7           0000000","email":"andrew@androiddocs.ru","skype":"andrew"}},       {"id":"2","name":"Ivan","city":"Kiev","contacts":{"mobile":"+38 0000000","email":"ivan@androiddocs.ru","skype":"ivan"}}]
}
```

мой интефейс

```
public interface Friends_API {

String BASE_URL = " http://androiddocs.ru/api/";

@GET("friends.json") Call<Friends> getFriends();

class Factory {

    private static Friends_API service;

    public static Friends_API getInstance(){
        if (service == null) {
            Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .build();

            service = retrofit.create(Friends_API.class);
            return service;
        } else {
            return service;
        }
    }
}
}
```

и POJO файлы сгенерированные ресурсом http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

и вот таким способом я забираю значение "data"

```
 Friends_API.Factory.getInstance().getFriends().enqueue(new Callback() { 
  @Override 
  public void onResponse(Call call, Response response){    

  String getData = response.body().getData(); }
  @Override
  public void onFailure(Call<Friends> call, Throwable t) {}
  }
```

не могу понять, каким способом я могу я могу получить значения полей id, name, city...
Заранее благодарен!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предположить что объект в который париться такой массив - это

```
public class MyObject{
   // Массив из Мапы-ключ , значение
    ArrayList<Map<...>> friends;
 }
```

Comment: `Friends friends = response.body();
                List<Friend> f = friends.getFriends();

                for (int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++) {

                    Log.i("TAG", "name:" + f.get(i).getName() +", City:" + f.get(i).getCity() + ", Contscts:" + f.get(i).getContacts().getEmail());
                }`

Answer (score 0):

У тебя должен быть бизнес модель (класс с данными, который включает в себя `id`, `name` и т.д.)
К примеру...

```
public clacc Friend {
   @SerializedName("id")
   private Int id;
   @SerializedName("name")
   private String name;
   //и так далее, все поля, то есть ключи json (файл json есть пара 
   //ключ - значение: "id":"1", "name":"Andrey", ...)
   //методы get, set
}
```

Далее класс хранящий `List<Friend> friends =` ...

```
public class FriendResponse {
    @SerializedName("friends")
    private List<Friends> friends = null;
    //методы get, set для List<>
}
```

В Friend_Api у тебя должен быть `Call<FriendRespons>` и в методе `onResponse` ты теперь можешь получить `response.getFriend()` - это и есть List<>, из которого получить данные уже не проблема. То есть, например,

```
friends.get(0).getId();
friends.get(0).getName();
```